# Regex ignore underscores

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

I have a regex `([-@.\/,':\w]*[\w])*` and it matches all words within a text (including punctuated words like I.B.M), but I want to make it exclude underscores and I can't seem to figure out how to do it... I tried adding `^[_]` (e.g. `(^[_][-@.\/,':\w]*[\w])*`) but it just breaks up all the words into letters. I want to preserve the word matching, but I don't want to have words with underscores in them, nor words that are entirely made up of underscores.

Whats the proper way to do this?

P.S.

- My app is written in C# (if that makes any difference).
- I can't use A-Za-z0-9 because I have to match words regardless of the language (could be Chinese, Russian, Japanese, German, English).

**Update**
Here is an example:

"I.B.M should be parsed as one word w_o_r_d! Russian should work too: мплекс исторических событий."

The matches should be:

```
I.B.M.  
should  
be  
parsed  
as  
one  
word  
Russian  
should  
work  
too  
мплекс  
исторических  
событий
```

Note that `w_o_r_d` should not get matched.

Comment: `^[_]` should be `[^_]`.  The former will match a `_` at the beginning of the string (or line if multiline).

Comment: @climbage, that definitely helped ignore underscores, but the underscores in the words still remain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
([-@.\/,':\p{L}\p{Nd}]*[\p{L}\p{Nd}])*
```

The `\w` class is composed of `[\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}]` when you're performing Unicode matching. (Or simply `[a-zA-Z0-9]` if you're doing non-Unicode matching.)

It's the `\p{Pc}` Unicode category -- punctuation/connector -- that causes the problem by matching underscores, so we explicitly match against the other categories without including that one.

(Further information here, ["Character Classes: Word Character"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#WordCharacter), and here, ["Character Classes: Supported Unicode General Categories"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories).)

Comment: `\p{L}` is the same as `[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Lm}]` which would significantly reduce your regex. See [Supported Unicode General Categories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories)

Answer (score 2):

Tue underscore comes from `\w`.

Simply use `A-Za-z0-9` instead.

Comment: Hey sidyll, thanks for the info, but unfortunately I can't use A-Za-z0-9 because I have to match words regardless of the language (could be Chinese, Russian, Japanese, German, English).

Answer (score 1):

For a more concise version of LukeH's regex, you can use simply:

```
([-@.\/,':\p{L}]*\p{L})*
```

I simply used `\p{L}` instead of `Lu, Ll, Lt, Lo, Lm`. See [Supported Unicode General Categories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=VS.100%29.aspx#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories)